# Comparator<File> implementation error

Tags: java, comparator

My application compares file names and one user got "comparison method violates its general contract java". But I cant reproduce error.

My question: Is it ok, when my @Override compare() method return 0, which means that object are equals?

This is my code:

Two types of sort: 1) by last modified date 2) by regex digit in file name.

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    int sortType;

    public FileComparator(int sortType) {
        this.sortType = sortType;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        int result;
        try {
            switch (sortType) {
                case Constants.SORT_BY_DATE:
                    result = f1.lastModified() > f2.lastModified() ? 1 : -1;
                    break;
                case Constants.SORT_BY_DIGID:
                    result = checkByDigit(f1, f2);
                    break;
                default:
                    result = f1.lastModified() > f2.lastModified() ? 1 : -1;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    private static int checkByDigit(File f1, File f2) {
        String regEx;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m1;
        Matcher m2;

        try {
            String f1Name = f1.getName().toUpperCase();
            String f2Name = f2.getName().toUpperCase();

            //  "ScanImage  _ 001"
            regEx = "(SCANIMAGE)(\\D*)(\\d+)";
            p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
            m1 = p.matcher(f1Name);
            m2 = p.matcher(f2Name);
            if (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
                return Integer.parseInt(m1.group(3)) > Integer.parseInt(m2.group(3)) ? 1 : -1;
            }

            //  "No_digits_here_001",""No_digits_here_002"
            regEx = "(\\D+)(\\d+)";
            p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
            m1 = p.matcher(f1Name);
            m2 = p.matcher(f2Name);
            if (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
                return Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)) > Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) ? 1 : -1;
            }

            // We didnt find any digit, use lexicographically compare
            return f1.compareTo(f2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sorting by last modified doesn't have a zero. So if they were last modified at the same time, then your comparator would break because the order of the arguments determines their order.

Comment: Also note, you might use a factory method design pattern to return a specific comparator depending on the given `sortType` rather than checking for it in the `compare()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific situation you run into problems comparing names such as `aaa_002`, `ccc_001` and `bbb`. Your code doesn't really decide what the correct order would be. One option is to sort all files that contain a numerical sequence after those that don't.

```
boolean m1find = m1.find();
boolean m2find = m2.find();

if(m1find || m2find) {
    if (m1find && m2find) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(m1.group(3)) > Integer.parseInt(m2.group(3)));
    } else {
            return Boolean.compare(m1find, m2find);
    }        
}
```

The problem could also some from lastModified times changing during sort, but it's unlikely to happen often.

Comment: Teemu, thank you. 
1) Sorry, is it exists `Boolean.compare()`? I should use `file1.compareTo(file2)` in this part?
2 )You code doesnt compare zzz.jpg and rrr.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

When you sort on last modified the order of the arguments matters, specifically when the last modified is the same time. Use [Long#compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-).